# Can I bound the following function by an integer?

Tags: functions

I am wondering if the following function

$$\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$$

can be bounded in some smart way by an integer.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ are integers, too?

Comment: That's not a function. What's the domain supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the function

$$f(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$$

satisfies

$$f(1/n,1/n)=\frac{2/n}{2/n^2}=n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$ So, the function is not bounded from above.

Also, $$f(-1/n,-1/n)=\frac{-2/n}{2/n^2}=-n, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$$ Thus, the function is not bounded from below.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can take every value if the variables are real numbers.
Each value $m\ne 0$ can be reached for example with $x=0$ and $y=\frac{1}{m}$.

If you have a function of integers than your function is always between $-1$ and $1$ since $|x+y|<x^2+y^2$.